# Django error 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django

Here is my very first app with Django. I keep getting the error `"'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'"`

Here is my view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Get most recent music for your listening pleasure</h1>"),
```

Comment: remove comma at the end.

Answer (score 3):

The comma at the end is turning the returned object into a tuple. Remove it and you should be fine.

Compare:

```
>>> def f():
...     return 1,
...
>>> type(f())
<class 'tuple'>
```

and

```
>>> def g():
...     return 1
...
>>> type(g())
<class 'int'>
```

Comment: I am such an empty vessel, that was very helpful thanks a million)))